# How to make confirmation code Input in react native

Tags: react-native

i am searching for a way to build a Confirmation Code button for an Phone Authentication process , i saw many npm modules for that but that doesn't work me . I just have no idea how can i custom the  from react-native , if someone have an idea , thanks

[image: example]

I tried to use this npm modules "react-native-confirmation-code-input" here [react-native-confirmation-code-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-confirmation-code-input)

but that is doesn't work for me , i have a blank screen ...
here is my code :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {Card, CardSection, Input, Button} from '../common';
import CodeInput from 'react-native-confirmation-code-input';

class PhoneForm extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)

}
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
};


onFulfill(isValid, code) {

}
render() {

return(
   <View>
    <CodeInput
      ref="codeInputRef2"
      keyboardType="numeric"
      codeLength={5}
      className='border-circle'
      compareWithCode='12345'
      autoFocus={false}
      codeInputStyle={{ fontWeight: '800' }}
      onFulfill={(isValid, code) => this.onFullFill(isValid, code)}
/>
   </View>
  );


 }
}


export default PhoneForm;
```

Comment: facing the same issue... please some one response

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue too, but first you need to do import style file after all the problem will be solved.

Comment: An example of doing that would be great here